# Configuring RAID10 with 6 drives on LSI Megaraid using storcli

Tags: raid-10, megaraid, storcli

I got a LSI 9271 card and 6 drives I want to add in RAID10 configuration - 3 spans of RAID1 to be exact.

All of the documentation shows the procedure via WebBIOS creating 3 DGs and spanning them.
The storcli command doesn't have dg or span parameters.

Is the pdperarray parameter used in this case, e.g. storcli /cx add vd r10 drives=252:0-5 PDperArray=2 ?

Comment: Can you provide a description or example of what the documentation tells you to do, and an example of what happens when you try to follow those directions? It's unclear to me what exactly the issue is.

Comment: [LSI User Guide](http://docs.avagotech.com/docs/12353236), page 75 provides WebBIOS procedure. I already have a server running (array unused though) so i got cli at my disposal.